# Sitecore 9.1 Installation - Skip to particular step

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

Hi I was installing sitecore 9.1 with SIF. It completed before `updatesolrschema`. When it was try to access to the below URL, because of proxy issue SIF script failed.

I know this was the last step in the Sitecore 9.1 installation. Then I was wondering how to get the Sitecore admin password.

Then I deleted the database and reinstalled again without proxy issue.

```
[-------------------------------------------------------------- SitecoreXP0_UpdateSolrSchema : SitecoreUrl -------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[SitecoreXP0_UpdateSolrSchema]:[Authenticating] http://sc91v.sc/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all
```

My question: Is there any way we can skip the number of steps in SIF to execute from a particular step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes is possible :

You can use something like :

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Skip CreateBinding
```

Where The name of task you want to skip is in the corresponding JSON configuration file that you are installing.

E.g. the task above (CreateBinding) is in Master_SingleServer.json:

[image]

To skip multiple steps, just supply a comma separated list of tasks, e.g.:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Skip CreateBinding, InstallSolrCores
```

More information you can find here: https://sitecoredude.com/how-to-skip-tasks-in-sitecore-installation-framework-sif/

Answer (score 1):

From Sitecore 9.2 (installing with SIF 2.2.0), you can also use -From parameter if you want to start from a particular task (skipping all previous tasks), which is very handy if your install fails towards the end.

Here are  examples from Install-SitecoreConfiguration.md:

#### EXAMPLE 3

```
PS C:\> Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\MyConfig.json -Skip Alpha,Beta
```

Starts an installation based on a JSON configuration file and executes all tasks except the named tasks.

#### EXAMPLE 4

```
PS C:\> Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\MyConfig.json -From Beta
```

Starts an installation based on a JSON configuration file and executes from the
specified task.

#### EXAMPLE 5

```
PS C:\> Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\MyConfig.json -From Alpha -To Beta
```

Starts an installation based on a JSON configuration file and executes from the
task named `Alpha` to the task named `Beta`.